# How do You structure an iPhone Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, structure

What are good ways of building groups/folders?

I've tried by feature (UI for a feature plus model etc) with a common group. I've also tried by UI, model, etc.

The former keeps like things together which fits the iPhone paradigm nicely. The latter means I jump around a bit more.

What do you think?

Comment: I'm increasingly using VIPER now with a large portion of the structure using services (abstractions over API, system, etc) to contain logic.

Answer (score 24):

The standard Xcode MVC folder structure is as follows.

1. **CoreData** : Contains DataModel and Entity Classes.
2. **Extension** : Contain One class(default apple class extensions+project class extensions.)
3. **Helper**: Contain Third Party classes/Frameworks (eg. SWRevealController) + Bridging classes (eg. Obj C class in Swift based project)
4. **Model** : Make a singleton class (eg.AppModel - NSArray,NSDictionary, String etc.) for saving data. The Web Service Response parsing and storing data is also done here.
5. **Services** : Contain Web Service processes (eg. Login Verification, HTTP Request/Response)
6. **View** : Contain storyboard, LaunchScreen.XIB and View Classes. Make a sub folder Cells -  contain UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewCell etc.
7. **Controller**: Contain Logic or Code related to UIElements (eg. UIButton’s reference+ clicked action)

Comment: In MVC can i have storyboard?

Comment: Yes you can. We can group multiple storyboards in View based on different modules as well.

Comment: isn't `Services` ambiguous?

Comment: Personally I suggest using the Uncle Bob approach from clean architecture. So, the structure and names should express business domains and not technical details and frameworks or pattern you are using.

Comment: Good idea, let's say in an application written in SwiftUI, is there a risk for the *View* to become cluttered for all the files responsible for different shapes, animations, etc. ? What would suggest that scenario?

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be very project dependent. In my last project I had mostly views, and so I organized the views by view-type.

Answer (score 2):

### Organizing code by type

Organizing code by type is ok for small projects but it's not a good practice for big ones.

Just imagine you have tons of files and folders organized by type, and when you work on a single feature, you have to open all of the folders. Which can confuse you and you can get lost many times while you scroll through files.

*It looks something like on [A.G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5259891/a-g)'s & [Julian B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922571/julian-b)'s [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983144/how-do-you-structure-an-iphone-xcode-project).*

### Organizing code by feature (intent)

Organizing code by feature (intent) is the best practice for big projects and big teams.

Cause usually teams work on a single feature, and they focus only on a single folder or group of files. They don't necessarily have to know about other features and files.

*It looks something like this:*

- AppDelegate
- Features

  - Feature 1

    - View Controllers
    - Models
    - Views
    - Logic
  - Feature 2

    - View Controllers
    - Models
    - Views
    - Logic
- Networking

  - Models
  - Logic
  - Extensions
- Resources

Also, to mention, this practice and technique (organizing project by feature) are implemented by the greatest companies around the world.

Comment: Since I posted the original question back in 2010 - wow! I’ve been doing this for a long time - this is very close to what I do. The key difference would be that I engage the core or App fabric and make heavy use of xcframeworks.

Comment: Glad to hear!

@ScottMcKenzie if this answer helped you, or you find it useful, please mark it as answered with the green tick under the voting ✅